# Yii 2 User Authentication & Role Based Access Control (RBAC) Module installation and usage

Tags: php, rbac, yii2

I am trying to install and use this  [robregonm / yii2-auth](https://github.com/robregonm/yii2-auth) module in my newly installed yii2 advance app.
I used composer to install it.
using this command

```
php composer.phar require robregonm/yii2-auth "dev-master"
```

I have configured my web and console files accordingly.
now I am trying to run migration as mentioned using

```
./yii migrate/up --migrationPath=@auth/migrations
```

And I am getting following error.

```
Exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Setting unknown property: yii\db\Connection::user'

in /var/www/mycoolapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php:196

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/mycoolapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(515): yii\base\Component->__set('user', Array)
#1 /var/www/mycoolapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Object.php(104): yii\BaseYii::configure(Object(yii\db\Connection), Array)
#2 [internal function]: yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)
#3 /var/www/mycoolapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(365): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#4 /var/www/mycoolapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(147): yii\di\Container->build('yii\db\Connecti...', Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/mycoolapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(341): yii\di\Container->get('yii\db\Connecti...', Array, Array)
#6 /var/www/mycoolapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php(132): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#7 /var/www/mycoolapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/MigrateController.php(124): yii\di\ServiceLocator->get('db')
#8 /var/www/mycoolapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(144): yii\console\controllers\MigrateController->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#9 /var/www/mycoolapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Controller.php(83): yii\base\Controller->runAction('up', Array)
#10 /var/www/mycoolapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(444): yii\console\Controller->runAction('up', Array)
#11 /var/www/mycoolapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(164): yii\base\Module->runAction('migrate/up', Array)
#12 /var/www/mycoolapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(140): yii\console\Application->runAction('migrate/up', Array)
#13 /var/www/mycoolapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(329): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request))
#14 /var/www/mycoolapp/yii(30): yii\base\Application->run()
#15 {main}
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'Unable to append to log file: /var/www/mycoolapp/console/runtime/logs/app.log' in /var/www/mycoolapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/log/FileTarget.php:87
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/mycoolapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/log/Target.php(103): yii\log\FileTarget->export()
#1 /var/www/mycoolapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/log/Dispatcher.php(179): yii\log\Target->collect(Array, true)
#2 /var/www/mycoolapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/log/Logger.php(162): yii\log\Dispatcher->dispatch(Array, true)
#3 [internal function]: yii\log\Logger->flush(true)
#4 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/mycoolapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/log/FileTarget.php on line 87
```

I am confused about whats missing here?
I can not find auth module anywhere in app.
My question is where should I clone yii2-auth in app?

Comment: Extension should be in /var/www/mycoolapp/vendor/robregonm/yii2-auth. Maybe in your config files something wrong, installation works correct in my system.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you misconfigured the `db` component in your config file, because, the `user` param does not exist, maybe you meant `username`. So the problem is not the extension itself but your local configuration setup.

Your `db` component should look like this:

```
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'pgsql:dbname=YourDbName...', // replace pgsql with your db driver
        'username' => 'YourUsername',
        'password' => 'YourPwd',
        'enableSchemaCache' => false,
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Change you console/config/main-local.php, replace the key **preload** with **bootstrap**.

```
return [
    'preload' => [
        //'debug',
    ],
    'modules' => [
        //'debug' => 'yii\debug\Module',
        //'gii' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    ],
];
```

TO

```
return [
    'bootstrap' => [
        //'debug',
    ],
    'modules' => [
        //'debug' => 'yii\debug\Module',
        //'gii' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    ],
];
```